# Mysql issue - function doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason I'm not able to retrieve the information I wanted from bids. I want it to display all the bids for this current item.
Is something wrong with the db, query or php?
the other functions work, just the `bid[bidprice]` doesn't. When I try to get it to display it wont show etc.

```
/*
============
db class
============
*/

public function allbids($id){
        $qry = "SELECT userName , bidPrice as bidPrice FROM bids , users WHERE productID =                $id";
        $rs = $this -> db -> query($qry);
        if($rs) {
            if($rs ->num_rows > 0) {
                $bid = $rs -> fetch_assoc();

            }
            return $bid;

        } else {
            echo 'Error Executing Query';   
        }
        return false;
    }


/*
============
html php
============
*/
 <?php

class ProductView extends View {
    protected function displayContent() {
        if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        //get the record from database
            $this -> product = $this -> model -> getProductByID($_GET['id']);
            $this -> bidprice = $this -> model ->allbids($_GET['id']);
                if(is_array($this -> product)) {
                    $html = $this -> displayProduct();
                    } else {

                       $html .= '<p>Sorry, that product is not available</p>';

                    }            
                        } else {
                         header("Location:index.php?page=error");

        }
            return $html;
    }


    private function displayProduct() {

            $html = '<div id="product">';
            $html .= '<img src="images/products/'.$this -> product['productImage'].'" alt="'.$this -> product['productName'].'" />';
            $html .= '<h3>'.$this -> product['productName'].'</h3>';
            $html .= '<p><strong>$'.$this -> product['productPrice'].'.00'.'</strong></p>';
            //.sprintf("%.2f" result was breaking the query placed .00. to give it currency rate.
            $html .= '<p>'.$this -> product['productDescription'].'</p>';
            $html .= '<p>'.$this -> bidprice['bidprice'].'</p>';
               foreach($this -> bidprice as $val)
        {
            $html .= '<p> Bid Price'.$val['bidPrice'].'</p>';
            $html .= '<p> Bidded By'.$val['userName'].'</p>';
        }

            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .='<div id="space">';
            $html .='</div>';

        return $html;        
    }    
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: doesn't it gives any error ?

Comment: normally when I face this problem I copy the $qry with a sample $id (in this case) and try to run it from mysqlworkbench or similar, this way you can discard if it's php or mysql's bad

Comment: what is error you recieve?

Comment: Seriously guys, just at look at his query. It should be fairly clear why it isn't working as the OP expects...

Comment: the query must be using joins and moreover if not that, he needs to mention productId is in which table

Comment: Seems you had posted again, but according to me you are only fetching one record from table, you must have to fetch all the records of bids for any particular product id.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your query to specify the tables from which the fields should be taken:

```
SELECT `users`.`userName` AS `userName`, 
       `bids`.`bidPrice` AS `bidPrice` 
FROM `bids`, `users` 
WHERE `bids`.`productID` = $id
```

For the above, I have assumed that the `productID` field is contained within the `bids` table. Furthermore, you're only ever fetching the first returned record from the set. If you want to get the entire bid history, you'll need to use a `while()` loop and then write each record to a `bids` array, and then return it.

Something like this should achieve what you're trying to do:

```
public function allbids($id)
{
    $qry = "SELECT `users`.`userName` AS `userName`, 
            `bids`.`bidPrice` AS `bidPrice` 
            FROM `bids`, `users` 
            WHERE `bids`.`productID` = $id";

    $rs = $this->db->query($qry);
    if($rs) 
    {
        $bids = array();
        while($bid = $rs->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $bids = $bid
        }
        return $bids;
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo 'Error Executing Query';   
        return false;
    }
}
```

Calling `allbids(1)` will return an array of bid records for the product ID `1`, or `false` if there was an error with the query.

Comment: this is the answer it generates but not the bids

Comment: Sorry? That comment doesn't mean a lot to me?

Comment: Bid Pricea

Bidded Bya

Bid Price1

Bidded By1

Comment: Still not really understanding your point, I'm afraid. What do you expect to be the result from running this query?